Change the background color of Editable item when it is being edited in Qt C++ using a stylesheet
I have a QListWidget which has items in it that can be edited(its a to do list), every item has the value Qt::ItemIsEditable which allows me to double click to edit the text value, however when i do this the textbox turns to black, i want to change the background color from black to something else, does anyone know how to do that?
Here is the code that creates all the items in the list
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)

{
ui->setupUi(this);
QFile file(path);

if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    QMessageBox::information(0, "error", file.errorString());
}

QTextStream in(&file);

while(!in.atEnd()) {
    QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem(in.readLine(), ui->listWidget);
    if(item->checkState())
    {
        item->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
    }
    else
    {
        item->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
    }

    item->setForeground(QBrush(Qt::black));

    ui->listWidget->addItem(item);
    item->setFlags(item->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);

}

file.close();

}
Im also using QSS stylesheet:
QListWidget::indicator:checked {
    image: url(:/resources/images/sillycat.jpg);
}

QListWidget::item:selected {
    background-color: #9de0be;
    color: black;
}

QListWidget::item:editable {
    background-color: white;
}


Please provide an appropriate [mre], most importantly, if the UI already uses QSS, include that as well (possibly removing anything else that is unrelated to the issue).

Sorry but your update is not sufficient, as, based on what you provide, what you report should not happen. Please take your time and provide a proper [mre] we can easily copy/paste/build/run, including the UI file (and check it on your own). Also add relevant build environment info, including OS and Qt versions.

Try this:
ui->listWidget->setStyleSheet("QListView QLineEdit{background:green}");;


How would you go about doing this in a stylesheet, im using a qss stylesheet currently
